# Textbox Border Not Showing - WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox

The `textbox` top and bottom `border` is not showing.

[image]

I have provided the entire XAML code for the main window. I have tried increasing the `BorderThickness` and also changed the `BorderBrush`. That did not work.
**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Activation Window" Height="300" Width="518.797">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Margin="23,171,0,76" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSecondDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Margin="81,171,0,76"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtThirdDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Margin="138,171,0,76"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFourthDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Margin="195,171,0,76"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFifthDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Margin="252,171,0,76"/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Product key:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="23,142,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstDigit_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="274" Margin="23,111,0,136" />
        <Label x:Name="label_Copy" Content="Email:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="23,81,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstDigit_Copy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" Margin="23,55,0,192" />
        <Label x:Name="label_Copy1" Content="First Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="23,25,0,0"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstDigit_Copy2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" Margin="167,55,0,192" />
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="142,220,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="222,220,0,0" Click="button1_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="350,147,0,0"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: post your code that produces this

Comment: @mrsargent I have included some part of the code section

Comment: You may need to post all of your code for the area you are having problems with.   I pasted in the code for your `textbox` and the entire border shows for me.

Comment: I added the code as screenshot.

Comment: can you edit your post and just copy in the code like you did previously instead of a screenshot?  It's easier to debug that way.

Comment: Why would you add it as a screenshot? To give us more work to type it out? :)

Comment: I have more code than text.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is.  Just copy to code you took a screen shot of and paste it where your current xaml is.

Comment: I have provided the entire XAML code.

Comment: You code works fine for me.  Has all four sides around the textbox.  Makes me think something funny is going on with the designer.  Do you have the same problem when you run the application?  Have you tried restarting visual studio?  Just some thoughts as I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It happens when I run the application but shows well on design mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="label_Copy1" Grid.Row="0" Content="First Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="23,0,0,0" />

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstDigit_Copy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" Margin="23,0,0,0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstDigit_Copy2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" Margin="11.5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Label x:Name="label_Copy" Grid.Row="2" Content="Email:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="23,0,0,0" />

    <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstDigit_Copy" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="270" Margin="23,0,0,0" />

    <Label x:Name="label" Grid.Row="4" Content="Product key:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="23,0,0,0" />

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFirstDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Margin="23,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSecondDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45"  Margin="11.5,0,0,0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtThirdDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45"  Margin="11.5,0,0,0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFourthDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45"  Margin="11.5,0,0,0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFifthDigit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="45"  Margin="11.5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="6">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="132,0,0,0" />
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="11.5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Indeed this is a much better way to accomplish what he is trying to do but how would this affect the problem with the textbox border?

Comment: He uses all kinds of `Margin` properties (I don't really like positioning stuff with that). His problem actually goes away if he resizes his `Window` to lets say 315. So the different "rows" created by his `Margin` settings cuts off the borders of the controls.